# IF statement for a tax sheet does not work

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am working on a tax sheet in Excel, with alot of if statements to capture each of the different tax rates. I am currently stuck on the last if statement, but I cannot get it to work, no matter how much I change it. I will add some pictures so I can showcase it better.
The If statement in itself is located in K26.
It looks like this
[image]
This works by changing the highlited cells.
[image]

The problem is that it works up to 20 000 000 NOK, but a number higher than that in AM24 does not show in K26. I am pretty convinced it's a problem with the second part of the statement, but I can't get it to work no matter how I approch the funktion.

I have tried both adding values as numbers in the IF statement.
[image]
I have also tried changing the numbers with the coresponding Cell values, but nothing seems to work, I am prettyr shure it's an easy solution, but I can't see it clearly.

Comment: I would look to set this up with a table of values and vlookup().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use vlookup() as that is much easier to control and edit as the rates and threshholds change:

[image]

```
VLOOKUP(E3,$B$4:$C$7,2,1)
```

Th 1 as the final argument controls how vlookup gets the match.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` is far better and easy way, whereas using multiple nested `IF()`s sometimes can be cumbersome. Also `LOOKUP()` works `=LOOKUP(E3,$B$4:$C$7)`

Answer (score 0):

Between value on the AM24 won't work with two operators (< & >). Try following way:

```
=IF(AND(AM24>=1700001, AM24<=20000000), 0, 1)
```