# Excel VLOOKUP based on list of range values

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

Does anybody have an idea how to do vlookup based on a list or from-to ranges?

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | From | To | Value |
| 2 | 100 | 200 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 200 | 300 | 0.75 |
| 4 | 300 | 400 | 0.90 |

For example, I would need to find value in column C based on input value that belongs to one of A->B ranges. Let's say if input value is 374. Function would need to return 0.90.

Note that IF is not an option, as I have too many From-To ranges.

Thanks in advance,
Ed

I could not find anything that would help me achieve requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IF statement for a tax sheet does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75782215/if-statement-for-a-tax-sheet-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

This formula works with the value to check in cell A6, e.g. 374.

```
=IF(MATCH(A6,A2:A4,1)=MATCH(A6,B2:B4,1)+1,INDEX(C2:C4,MATCH(A6,A2:A4,1)),NA())
```

Quick explanation :

1. `MATCH(A6,A2:A4,1)` get the last row index among range A2:A4 where the value is under or equal to A6. With your worksheet and the value 374, this formula returns 3. It is the row of the lower bound of the From-To interval you search.
2. Same with `MATCH(A6;B2:B4;1)`. This returns 2. It is the row of the previous upper bound of the From-To interval you search.
3. The test between the 2 MATCH formula is here to ensure that there is no ambiguity with your From-To ranges (like holes with no solution, or ranges that overlaps, with multiple solutions).
4. The success value of the `IF` test is given by `INDEX(C2:C4,MATCH(A6,A2:A4,1))`. It is the nth element in the Value column (in fact in range `C2:C4`), of the first match that we got in point 1 of this explaination. It relies on `INDEX` function.
5. The failed value of the IF test returns a non-available error (`NA` function). This happens if there is any hole between the From-To ranges.

Anyway, to work properly, you still need sorted values in columns From and To. Otherwise, you might have to deal with VBA to get it done.